# TradingView Charting Library consuming Custom Data Points in Custom Studies

Tags: tradingview-api

I'm looking into the [TradingView Charting Library](https://www.tradingview.com/charting-library-docs/) and trying to create a [custom study](https://www.tradingview.com/charting-library-docs/latest/custom_studies/Custom-Studies-Constructor), which can consume some custom data points, apart from the standard OHLCV data points, for e.g. `AvgPrice`, `Turnover` etc.

But unfortunately, I haven't found a way to do this out of the box.

To test this, I tried returning some mock data in the [`getBars`](https://www.tradingview.com/charting-library-docs/latest/connecting_data/Datafeed-API#getbars) function, with some custom data points.
However, the custom data points are not available in the `context` object that is passed to the [`main`](https://www.tradingview.com/charting-library-docs/latest/custom_studies/Custom-Studies-Constructor#maincontext-inputcallback) function of the custom study (which is called for each bar).

So, does anyone know if it's possible to supply custom data points and be able to consume them in your custom studies?

The only dirty way so far is to cache the data in the `getBars` function call, and then use it in the `main` function of the custom study. Obviously, this is not an efficient or preferable way to do this.